# I want to extract array from json file

Tags: automation, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

i have json file with this data
[
{
“rolename”: “Number one”,
“roledescription”: “Number one”,
“rolepermission”: [“manage_users”,“view_user_logs”],
“roletype”: “client”

}
]

i want to extract data from “rolepermission” and put it in body request
this api accept data like this
{

"role": {

```
"name": "Test",

"description": "Test",

"permissions": [

    "manage_users",

    "manage_role",

    "managing_custom_page"

],

"userType":"admin"
```

}
}
and i convert it to this to extract data from my json file
{

"role": {

```
"name": "{{rolename}}",

"description": "{{roledescription}}",

"permissions": [

    "{{rolepermission}}"

],

"userType": "{{roletype}}"
```

}
}

but he send request like this

“permissions”: [
“manage_users,view_user_logs”
],

instead it should send it like this
“permissions”: [
“manage_users”,
“view_user_logs”
],

what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save array data, you need `stringify` first which is mentioned here https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#understanding-variables

```
const res = pm.response.json();
const rolepermission = res.data[0].rolepermission;
pm.environment.set("rolepermission", JSON.stringify(rolepermission));
```

Use this variable in request body:

```
{
  "role": {
    "name": "{{rolename}}",
    "description": "{{roledescription}}",
    "permissions": {{rolepermission}},
    "userType": "{{roletype}}"
  }
}
```